# 502 Error with nginx and Mamp on Yosemite

Tags: nginx, mamp, osx-yosemite

I recently read that MAMP has build-in Nginx now. Since I always wanted to try out nginx I deleted XAMPP and switched to MAMP.

So I installed MAMP under Yosemite, changed the Apache and Nginx Port to 80 and the MySQL Port to 3306. My Document root is the MAMP htdocs folder and the Webserver is Nginx.

localhost/MAMP opened by default and I instantly got 502 Bad Gateway.
Same for any folder in htdocs.

Now when I simply type in 'localhost' it gives me a 403 Forbidden Error.
Also when I use '127.0.0.1'.

I really don't know what to do. Tried using chmod 775 on every folder since I often run into 'permission denied' for no apparent reason. Changing folder and file permissions usually does the trick but now I just dunno.